# Node.js Express req.query is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm running the following code on Node.js with Express 4.7.2

```
express.get('/test1',function(req, res) {
  var ttt = false;
  if (req.query.username === undefined) ttt = true;
  res.json({query: ttt});
});
```

I call the URL:

> {{protocol}}://{{server}}/test1?username=1

And I get the result:

> {query: true}

Which shows `req.query.username` is indeed `undefined`

What am I missing? How come the query param is not passed in?

Comment: How are you "calling the URL"? Using cURL? A browser? Something else?

Comment: Both a browser (chrome) and Postman. Same result

Comment: I had this problem. Turns out it was a spelling mistake. I was using `querry` instead of `query`

Comment: Can you console log req.query object and see what is the result

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown works fine for me with node v0.10.30 and express 4.8.7:

```
var app = require('express')();

app.get('/test1',function(req, res) {
  var ttt = false;
  if (req.query.username === undefined) ttt = true;
  res.json({query: ttt});
});

app.listen(8000);
```

I then navigate to `http://localhost:8000/test1?username=1` and it displays `{"query":false}`.

Comment: but `username=1` and it should be returning `{query: true}`

Comment: Not with the logic in the original code. I just copied it verbatim.

Comment: I have same problem: `req.query` is undefined for me: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45928112/630169 What is the problem could be?!

Answer (score 0):

It seams that query `typeof` is string, and string of "undefined" is truthy.

In your code it should be:

```
if (req.query.username === "undefined")
  ttt = true;
```