# Query string variables still empty in Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, query-string

Write simple server as suggested here on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710358/how-to-retrieve-post-query-parameters):

**rest_api.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// Initialize RESTful server
const app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(bodyParser.json() );                        // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));   // to support URL-encoded bodies

// Spin up the server
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('running on port', app.get('port'))
});

app.post('/bookinghandler', function (req, res) {
    let senderId = req.query.sender;
    let email = req.query.email;
    let hotelName = req.query.hotelName;
    let confirmNumber = req.query.confirmNumber;
    let start = req.query.startDate;
    let end = req.query.endDate;
}
```

**app.js:**

```
// This loads the environment variables from the .env file
require('dotenv-extended').load();

const builder = require('botbuilder');
const restify = require('restify');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = require("./bot")
bot.InitializeBot(connector);

// Load REST API module
var restApi = require("./rest_api");
```

And want to get parameters through query string (sample request in URL: `bookinghandler?sender=100000250242810&email=some@email.com&hotelName=Grand Hotel&confirmNumber=654321&startDate=2017-10-11&endDate=2017-10-15`).

However `req.params`, `req.param()`, `req.body`, `req.query` are still empty. What I'm doing wrong? Is it the only way to do it through [`require('url')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33859650/630169) or [`require('qs')`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5710916/630169)? If I want to it through express only?

Comment: Hum usually if you are looking for query parameters it should be a GET method no? `app.get(...)`

Comment: @MarcoTalento, probably however GET does not work for me as well -- all is empty.

Comment: While making changes, did you remember to restart the server?

Comment: @Boaz sure! :) Otherwise it returns `Cannot GET /bookinghandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in using 2 REST frameworks: express and restify. Need to make entire application as restify or express app. Before I had a restify server and inside that another express server was created (just took different examples). Generally need to use one or the other, not both.

**Modified app.js:**

```
// This loads the environment variables from the .env file
require('dotenv-extended').load();

const builder = require('botbuilder');
const restify = require('restify');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.use(require('restify-plugins').queryParser());
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Index route
server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('My chat bot')
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = require("./bot")
bot.InitializeBot(connector);

// Load REST API module
var restApi = require("./rest_api");

// POST request from webview page
server.post('/bookinghandler', restApi.BookingHandler);
```

**Modified rest_api.js:**

```
const service = require("./service");

module.exports.BookingHandler = async function (req, res, next) {
    let senderId = req.query.sender;
    let email = req.query.email;
    let hotelName = req.query.hotelName;
    let confirmNumber = req.query.confirmNumber;
    let start = req.query.startDate;
    let end = req.query.endDate;

    res.send(200);  // Success
    return next(false);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/bookinghandler', function (req, res) {
       let senderId = req.query.sender;
       let email = req.query.email;
       let hotelName = req.query.hotelName;
       console.log(req.query, senderId, email, hotelName)
})
```

Prints this output in my terminal

`{ sender: '100000250242810',
  email: 'some@email.com',
  hotelName: 'Grand' } '100000250242810' 'some@email.com' 'Grand'`

Comment: Using Advanced REST client to send the request or even via browser. All variables and query are undefined to me - `console.log(req.query, senderId, email, hotelName)` output: `[Function: getQuery] undefined undefined undefined`

Comment: Main question why it is working for You, and does not work for me?! Could there be conflict with `resitfy`? Also I call this code from `app.js` like following: `var restApi = require("./rest_api");`

Comment: Can you please post the code for where you set your cookies for the session?

Comment: It is not a web app - server app, backend, no cookies, no session, etc.

Comment: What are You talking about? I'm not using or checking `req.session`.

Comment: my bad, i thought the code in the response below was what you used in your program

Comment: this strange guy @turmuka messed things up.

Comment: How are you making this post request? I am using Postman and it works in there

Comment: Could you provide the code for the rest of the application? You mentioned you have an app.js file, what file is this route located in?

Comment: app.js provided - no secret here :) See code above.

Comment: You should really just be making this entire application an express app, right now you seem to have a restify server and inside that you are creating another express server. Generally you use one or the other, not both.

Comment: You are right! Simple application on `express` works fine. You may add this as an answer. Will make all in `restify`, need to see how to listen on 2 ports with it or will run on single port.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome res.query undefined issue by using JSON.parse

```js
const queryValues= JSON.parse(req.query.queriesHere);
console.log(queryValues);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Whenever a request is  made with queries, the queries must exist in
>   the url for the server to recognize *them*.

Here is a sample code for you. You need to add the queries to action in your html form. You also separate them by using `&`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/as/?sender=321&email=myemail@email.com" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="myName" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="ssss">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is `app.js`

```
app.post('/bookinghandler', function (req, res) {

    var senderId = req.query.sender;
    var email = req.query.email;
    console.log('senderId = ' + senderId + ' email = ' + email);
    res.end("got the info");
});
```

Now, you are going to ask me the purpose of this since we are already defining them in the *form*. Well, real websites don't do it. If you want to evaluate your queries you need to leave them ***blank*** and see if the user has any cookies on the browser.

This is the html form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/as/?sender=&email=" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="myName" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="" value="ssss">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is our app

```
app.post('/bookinghandler', function (req, res) {
    if(req.session.user.id){  //checking the cookies if the user is logged in/exists
       var senderId = req.query.sender;
       var email = req.query.email;
    }else{
     res.send("you haven't logged in");
     return false;
    }

    console.log('senderId = ' + senderId + ' email = ' + email);
    res.end("got the info");
});
```

For more info on the node module for **cookies** please see [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

***Conclusion***

Queries on a form is mostly extra work, the work could be done easily by only using `req.body` and cookies, `req.session` objects. People don't usually use it unless they have an extra data to transfer between the client and the server.

***UPDATE***

Parameters are defined like this `/:param` in node.js

if you wanna use params

```
app.get('/bookinghandler/:myParam/?queriesHere='){
   console.log(req.params.myParam + "   and the query: " + req.query.queriesHere);

res.send(req.params.myParam + "   and the query: " + req.query.queriesHere);
}
```

add this code, and copy and go to this url [localhost:5000/bookinghandler/hereisaparam/?queriesHere=123](http://#)

make sure to add port

if it's a server app, create another node.js file and then run them both

**otherfile.js**

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://localhost:5000/bookinghandler/hereisaparam/?queriesHere=123', function (error, response, body) {
  if(error){
console.log(error):
return false;
}
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the data
});
```

Run this file while the server is running.

Comment: I'm not sending query from website or whatever: just URL in browser or Advanced REST client. URL is simple: `localhost:5000/bookinghandler?sender=100000250242810&email=some@email.com&hotelName=Grand%20Hotel&confirmNumber=654321&startDate=2017-10-11&endDate=2017-10-15`

Comment: `req.url` is correct: `/bookinghandler?sender=100000250242810&email=some@email.com&hotelName=Grand%20Hotel&confirmNumber=654321&startDate=2017-10-11&endDate=2017-10-15` However parameters still undefined.

Comment: that's because you don't have any parameters in that url @AlekseyKontsevich

Comment: I do not use any forms or pages, GET does not work as well as I mentioned above.

Comment: are you trying to do make a simple post request?

Comment: if this the kind of code you'd want? what do you want exactly? @AlekseyKontsevich

Comment: I am sorry @AlekseyKontsevich . I understood wrong, i used without restify